# TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable

Tags: python

```
from file import x
a = x
if i in a:
    dosomething
```

file.py:

```
class x:
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = []

    def __contains__(self,item):
        return item in self.q

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in self.q:
            yield i
```

Появляется ошибка:
`TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable`

Что я делаю не так и как сделать верно?

Comment: вам стоит конкретнее указать вывод программы

Answer (score 2):

Работу нужно делать не с классом (типом), а с объектом. Для этого нужно у класса вызвать конструктор через `()`.

Попробуйте:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = []

    def __contains__(self,item):
        return item in self.q

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in self.q:
            yield i

a = X()
a.q.append(1)
a.q.append(2)
a.q += [3, 4, 5]


if 5 in a:
    print('5!')

for i in a:
    print(i)
```

---

**PS.**

Классы принято называть с верхнего регистра.